# Count Non-Substring Overlapping

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program allows user to input a string. End the program is printing out:

a. How many words that repeated itself.
For example: 'This is Jake and Jake is 24 years old'
The console must print out '4' because 'is' and 'Jake' are the word that repeated

b. Remove all the repeated word. Print out the rest: 'This and 24 years old'

c. Print out which repeated words have been removed

So the idea is the user can type whatever they want, 'This is Jake and Jake is 24 years old' is just an example. The hardest part is how can console check all the repeated words without a substring?

Comment: Have you tried solving this homework question yourself yet?  And, if so, can you include your Python script?

Comment: I can only do it with substring sorry

Comment: Please show your attempt(s)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? 
Here is what I am doing.

First I grab the user input, then I convert the string to a list splitting on spaces between words. Then I count the occurence of the words, if the wordcount is greater than 1, I add it to a dictionary , where the key is the word and the value is the count of the words that exist in the string. 
After printing out the repeated words, I remove the strings that find a mention in the dictionary.

**Note** - This code can be improved so much but I purposely did it such a manner to make it easier to understand. You should not be using this code if its a production system.

```
string = input("Enter your string : ")

items = {}
words = string.split(" ")

for word in words:
    wordCount = words.count(word)
    if(wordCount > 1): 
        items[word] = wordCount

print("There are {0} repeated words".format(len(items)))

updateString = ""
for item in items:
    updateString =string.replace(item,"")

print(updateString)
print(items)
```

**Updated**

```
string = input("Enter your string : ")

items = {}
words = string.split(" ")

for word in words:
    wordCount = words.count(word)
    if(wordCount > 1): 
        items[word] = wordCount

print("There are {0} repeated words".format(len(items)))


for item in items:
    string = string.replace(" {0} ".format(item)," ")

print(string)
print(items)
```

Comment: can you remove all the strings that mentioned in the dictionary not just one?

Comment: I guess it should be easy at this point for you :) .. If you are stuck , please show us some work and we will try to resolve your questions.. Good luck !

Comment: I did same as you but I change replace(item,'') into items.clear() but it no help. I'm just a begineer for 2 weeks now :)